# Java 8 stream's max(Math::max)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When I did the test, I meet a problem with the stream.

The code is below:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {

    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(-2, -5, -7, -16);
    Integer integer = integers.stream().max(Math::max).orElse(0);
    System.out.println(integer);

    }
}
```

The return value is -15, the minimum number in the list. 
But when I change max() to min(), it returns me the max value. Why?

Comment: `integers.stream().min(Math::min).orElse(0)` ... this returns `-2` for me.

Comment: `Math.max(-2, -5)` returns `-2`, how does `Stream.max` interpret that result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is somehow very subtle, let's take two at a time:

```
 -2, -5 => Max between these two is "-2"
```

It is a *negative* result, since `max` method from a `stream` accepts a `Comparator`, which says:

> returns a negative integer if the first argument is less than the second.

Thus according to your `Comparator` , you have just said that `-5` > `-2` or in simpler words:

```
Stream.of(-2, -5)
            .max(Math::max)
            .ifPresent(System.out::println); // will show -5
```

You can build your logic for the other numbers from here and understand why `-16` is the result that you get.

To make this correct, you need:

```
 ...max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
   ....
```

Comment: Could you please explain why I compare " -2, -5" twice, which first we compare inside Math::max, and then compare in the max()?

Comment: @lbrobinho I don't understand your comment, sorry. Think about it a bit, `stream::max` expects a `Comparator` and you say that this `Comparator` is implemented by using `Math::max`

Comment: So it is related with the order right?

Comment: @lbrobinho again, I am not in the world of reading minds here... *what* order?

Comment: if the array is -16, -7 ,-5, -2, so it is correct answer, and I tried naturalOrder(), and understand what you said. Thank you.